# Boot problems after installing Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, boot, windows, grub2, mbr

After installing Linux Debian on external HDD (not live Boot), is no booting possible. If I start the PC it automaticly jumps in grub-rescue. How should I fix it? On the Internal HDD is just Windows 10 installed.

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: That's a very broad question. Have you install ubuntu on your PC's internal HDD as well? Have you tried to use `sudo grub-install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answerer by [Anwar](https://askubuntu.com/users/61218/anwar) on [Askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-prompt-shows-up-instead)**

If you were able to boot Ubuntu in the past, but not now, follow these steps to solve the problem.

- First type `ls` command and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see all the available
  partitions. The entries will be shown as `(hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos5)` etc.
- Then type ls `(hd0,msdos1)/` to see the content of the drive. if you
  see entries like `vmliuz` or `initrd`, it is your Linux partition. If you
  fail with (hd0,msdos1), try with (hd0,msdos2) and so on, until you
  recognize your Ubuntu partition.
- When you correctly identify your Ubuntu partition, type
  `root=(hdX,msdosX)` , replace the `X` with correct identified number. For
  example, if you see `vmlinuz` and `initrd` entries by entering `ls`
  `(hd0,msdos5)`, the command will be `root=(hd0,msdos5)`.
- then type `configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will
  bring you Previous Ubuntu grub menu.
- Then choose the entry to boot Ubuntu.
- After you booted up, Open a terminal and type sudo update-grub and
  press Enter. This will update the grub menu and prevent future
  problems.

**In the case that you are not able to boot to Ubuntu after installation, re-installing Ubuntu is the best option. You can check this question:**

- [How to install Ubuntu OS Having already installed Windows OS](https://askubuntu.com/q/141108/61218)